# rssニュースアプリのリジェクト対策

Tags: swift, ios

私はニュースアプリをiOS版でリリースしています。
しかし、2ヶ月前のアップデートでリジェクトされました。
理由はガイドラインの4.2.2です。
シンプルでありリンク集という理由です。ネイティヴ機能を追加したりしなさいとのことです。

アプリは複数のサイトのrssを取得している簡単なアプリです。
コンテンツはユーザー側がオリジナルサイトへアクセスして取得しています。
しかし、見た目はオリジナルサイトとは違うようにアプリ側で読み込みをして表示しています。

どのようにしたらアプリの審査に通るかヒントが欲しいです。
今私の考えている企画を提示します。

1を追加するのか2を追加するのか、それとも他の機能がよいのか教えてほしいです。

1.バックグランド更新
サイレントプッシュでappを起動しバックグランドで新しい記事を更新します。
ユーザーはappを起動した時に新しい情報をすぐに見ることができます。そしてオフラインでも閲覧をする事ができます。

2.データ取得方法の変更
今のappはサーバーからrssのリンク、タイトル、サムネイル情報だけを受け取り、コンテンツはオリジナルサイトへユーザー側で取得しています。
この方法を変えます。
全てのコンテンツをサーバーが取得してユーザーのアプリがこのデータを受信します。
ユーザーはオリジナルサイトにアクセスせずに記事を取得できます。
この方法でwebclippingではなくなると思いました。

Answer (score 1):

審査担当者によりけりなのですが、以前同様のアプリをリリースした際は、Apnsの実装でリリースできました。
人気の記事などをpush通知すればよいのではないでしょうか？
現在はリジェクトされる可能性があるかもしれません。